# Fetch for one row in PDF?

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a PDF from mySQL table. The PDF generated is for all values in table. I want it to be specific for one single row. For example, in the picture below, I want the PDF to be generated for ID-2. And similarly for all other rows. I have attached two php scripts. `fetch.php` is where I display the values with the `Generate PDF` button and `generate_pdf.php` is where I generate the PDF.

fetch.php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id12", "", "id12");
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Datas WHERE ID LIKE '%" .$_POST["search"]."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Wrongs</th>
                        <th>Rights</th>
                        <th>Percentage</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Generate PDF</th>
                    </tr>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Wrongs"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Rights"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Percentage"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["Age"].'</td>
                    <td><form class="form-inline" method="post" action="generate_pdf.php"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" id="pdf" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" aria-hidden="true"></i>Generate PDF</button></td>

                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;

}
else
{
    echo "Data not found";
}

?>
```

generate_pdf.php

```
<?php
//include connection file 
include_once("connection.php");
include_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{

}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
$display_heading = array('ID'=>'ID', 'Name'=> 'Name', 'Wrongs'=> 'Wrongs','Rights'=> 'Rights', 'Percentage' => 'Percentage', 'Age' => 'Age');

$result = mysqli_query($connString, "SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas") or die("database error:". mysqli_error($connString));
$header = mysqli_query($connString, "SHOW columns FROM Datas");

$pdf = new PDF();
//header
$pdf->AddPage();
//foter page
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
foreach($header as $heading) {
$pdf->Cell(40,12,$display_heading[$heading['Field']],1);
}
foreach($result as $row) {
$pdf->Ln();
foreach($row as $column)
$pdf->Cell(40,12,$column,1);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: GeneratingPDF]

Comment: In the query can you use WHERE id=2 so pdf will create only with 1 row no?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini how do I alter it in php script to only select the current row?

Comment: `"SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas WHERE id=$id"`  , in the button for export POST(with Ajax method) or use simple GET for create id in query.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Sorry but i do not understand, should I make the change in ```generate_pdf.php?```

Comment: see my answer and try it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Additionally be warned: your initial query (concatenating `$_POST["search"]` into the query) is widely open for SQL injection

Comment: @NicoHaase adding correction with all two tips

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For answer your comment, in fetch.php change button with a link button and ID from row:**

```
 <tr>
<td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Wrongs"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Rights"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Percentage"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Age"].'</td>
<td><a href="generate_pdf.php?id='.$row["ID"].'"><button  id="pdf" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" aria-hidden="true"></i>Generate PDF</button></a></td>
    </tr>
```

***Why do that?*** : 
This action allows you to pass the variable from one page to another (another method would be to use AJax)

**And in generate.pdf use GET for create variable and use it on query like:**

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
 $query = $connString->prepare("SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas WHERE ID=?");
$query->bind_param('i',$id);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();
```

***Why do that?*** : 
We will use the $ _GET variable by passing it in the query. unlike you I used prepared stmt to prevent direct attacks on the query.

**Another 'tips' change search query:**

```
$search='%'.$_POST["search"].'%';
$sql =$connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM Datas WHERE ID LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param('s',$search);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
```

***Why do that?*** : 
Exactly as seen before, it is absolutely necessary to prepare the query in order to prevent attacks

---

To answer your last comment:*@SimoneRossaini I forgot to mention one thing. My id is a string. How do I refer it? Since the reference script you gave was for integer.*

```
Character   Description
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

So you need to change bind_param like : `$query->bind_param('s',$id);`

Comment: Please don't use this code **ever** - it's widely open to SQL injection

Comment: Do you mean I should upvote that answer? Then please provide some explanation about it first such that it is a **good** answer that deserves an upvote. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from it, and just dumping code that is copied into an existing project does not help anybody to learn from your suggestins

Comment: In fact, I explain step by step

Comment: Did you? I haven't found an explanation why a button should be better than the form. And what do you mean by that "tips change search query"?

Comment: @NicoHaase It's well now?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini is there a way to open the PDF in a new page?

Comment: Add target blank to link like:`<a href="generate_pdf.php?id='.$row["ID"].'" target="_blank">`

Comment: ;) Don't worry!!

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I forgot to mention one thing. My ```id``` is a string. How do I refer it? Since the reference script you gave was for integer.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thank you so much. I wish I could give you lots of ice creams!